# Post/execute form field data to browser address bar

Tags: html, forms, url

I'm not an expert in php.  What I am trying to do is add a UPS tracking feature to my site.  In order to check tracking info for UPS all that is needed is the tracking number at the end of their tracking url like the following.

http://wwwapps.ups.com/WebTracking/track?track=yes&trackNums=1ZXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

How can I add a field on my site so that a user can enter the tracking number: 1ZXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX and then click a button which will open a new window or tab with the entire url?

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

trackNums is a GET variable. You can use a GET form.

```
<form method="get" action="http://wwwapps.ups.com/WebTracking/track" target="_blank">
    <input type="hidden" name="track" value="yes" />
    <label for="trackNums">Tracking #</label><input type="text" id="trackNums" name="trackNums" value="" />
    <input type="submit" value="Track" />
</form>
```

To keep the user on your website, but open this website in a new tab or window set the `target` attribute to `_blank`.

Comment: Thanks J. Money, that was exactly what I was trying to accomplish.  You're awesome!

Comment: And what is a get variable name for UPS_HTML_License?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this completely client-side:

```
<form action="http://wwwapps.ups.com/WebTracking/track" method="GET" target="_blank">
    <input type="hidden" name="track" value="yes"/>
    <input name="trackNums" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

The `target="_blank"` has it open in a new window/tab.

Comment: It's an example; I've no idea what his interface is supposed to look like. I saw no need to build a UI for a simple code example. target corrected to action.

Answer (score 0):

You tagged this with PHP, but there is no need to use PHP. This can be done in JavaScript. The JavaScript function is:

```
window.location.href = "http://wwwapps.ups.com/WebTracking/track?track=yes&trackNums="+trackingnumber;
```

Now, the key is to get the tracking number. That will be in a field on the database. Let's assume this is the field:

```
<input type='text' id='trnum'>
```

You get the value with:

```
var trackingnumber=document.getElementById('trnum').value;
```

That's all you need. Just call a function that changes the window.location.href using the value from the tracking number input field.

Comment: This solution doesn't open in a new window/tab as required by the OP.